# How to export data from VB6 to an HTML TextBox

Tags: html, vb6

I would like to know how can I export data from VB6 textbox to a HTML textbox? It could be a simple html page or an asp page.

for example, on my VB6 form, i have an name field. Upon clicking of a button on the VB6 form, the data in the name field will be exported to a textbox on the html page.

Thank you all for help and time for reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see this demo in action, and be able to follow it through and learn how to grab from it what you need:

Create a form with a lable over a textbox, and stick 1 command buttons on the form.  Don't rename any of them - the program expects the text1, command1

The following CODE is the complete FORM CODE to copy/paste into it.

Add refernce to your project from (Project=>References)Microsoft Internet Controls,Microsoft HTML Object Library,

```
Option Explicit

Public TargetIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Private Sub Command1_Click()  ' Send text to first IE-document found
    GetTheIEObjectFromSystem
    SendTextToActiveElementWithSubmitOptionSet (False)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Me.Text1 = "This is a sample text message set and submitted programmatically"  'make text1 multiline in design
    Me.Command1.Caption = "Text to the first IE browser document found"
End Sub

Public Sub GetTheIEObjectFromSystem(Optional ByVal inurl As String = ".") '  "." will be found in ALL browser URLs
   Dim SWs As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
   Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
   Dim Doc As Object
   For Each IE In SWs
        If TypeOf IE.Document Is HTMLDocument Then ' necessary to avoid Windows Explorer
            If InStr(IE.LocationURL, inurl) > 0 Then
                Set TargetIE = IE
                Exit For
            End If
      End If
   Next
   Set SWs = Nothing
   Set IE = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub SendTextToActiveElementWithSubmitOptionSet(ByVal bSubmitIt As Boolean)
    Dim TheActiveElement As IHTMLElement
    Set TheActiveElement = TargetIE.Document.activeElement
    If Not TheActiveElement.isTextEdit Then
        MsgBox "Active element is not a text-input system"
    Else
        TheActiveElement.Value = Me.Text1.Text
        Dim directParent As IHTMLElement
        If bSubmitIt Then
            Dim pageForm As IHTMLFormElement
            Set directParent = TheActiveElement.parentElement
            ' find its parent FORM element by checking parent nodes up and up and up until found or BODY
            Do While (UCase(directParent.tagName) <> "FORM" And UCase(directParent.tagName <> "BODY"))
                Set directParent = directParent.parentElement
            Loop
            If UCase(directParent.tagName) = "FORM" Then
                Set pageForm = directParent
                pageForm.submit  'intrinsic Form-element Method
            Else
                MsgBox ("Error: No form unit for submitting the text on this page!")
            End If
        End If
        Set pageForm = Nothing
        Set directParent = Nothing
    End If
    Set TheActiveElement = Nothing
    Set TargetIE = Nothing
End Sub
```